# How to get php statement checked first while working with Google Maps geocoder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a function which will allow user to add start and end coordinates into the database. The problem is that I am getting an error saying that **geometry is not defined**.

I have done few checks and I realized that the function does not even check php statement to see if $_POST['start'] and $_POST['end'] variable are empty.

Here is my PHP function to check if any of the fields are missing.

```
$error = "";

    if (!$_POST['start']) {
        $error = "Start point is missing.";

    } else if (!$_POST['end']) {
        $error = "End point is missing.";

    } else if (!$_POST['date']) {
        $error = "Date is missing.";

    if ($error != "") {

        echo $error;
        exit();

    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO offer (start, end, date, startLng, startLat, endLng, endLat) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['start'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['end'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['date'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['startLng'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['startLat'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['endLng'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['endLat'])."')";

        mysqli_query($link, $query);

        echo 1;
    }
```

Whenever user press button inside a modal it should start functions responsible for getting start and end coordinates.

```
$("#addNewModal").click(function() {
    getStartCoordinates();
})
```

Here are the function for getting start and end coordinates.

```
function getStartCoordinates() {

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': $("#start").val()
    },

        function(result, status) {
            if (status = google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

                startLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
                startLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
                getStartCoordinates();

            } else {

                getEndCoordinates();
            }
    }             
    );
}

function getEndCoordinates() {

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': $("#end").val()
    },

        function(result, status) {
            if (status = google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

                endLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
                endLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
                addRequest();    

            } else {

                addRequest();    
            }
    }             
    );
}
```

And AJAX for addCoordinates.php function.

```
function addRequest() {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addCoordinates.php",
        data: "start=" + $("#start").val() + "&end=" + $("#end").val() + "&date=" + $("#date").val() + "&startLng=" + startLng + "&startLat=" + startLat + "&endLng=" + endLng + "&endLat=" + endLat,
        success: function(result) {

            if (result == "1") {

                $("#alertSuccess").show();

            } else {

                $("#addAlert").html(result).show();
            }

        }
    })

}
```

**What I have found:**

1. With no values entered into any input, I am getting an error of
   geometry undefined.
2. If I enter values into both start and end fields then I am finally getting php response saying that `$error = "Date is missing."`
3. I can fix that error by adding if statement to the #addNewModal click function to check if both values for start/end fields are entered.

So the main point is how can I get my PHP response checked first so I can get both `$error = "Start point is missing.";` and `$error = "End point is missing.";` responses from my PHP function.

Comment: A typical way to do return multiple errors from the server. Which should just mean removing the else from `else if (!$_POST['end']) {` and `else if (!$_POST['date']) {` then appending the errors using concatenation like: ` $error .= "End point is missing.";`. The server would then report `$error = "Start point is missing.End point is missing."; which should better indicate to the user the issues.

Comment: That's a good idea. However, it still does not fix my issue. I think it is because it calls getStartCoordinates() function without checking if start and end inputs have been entered, but this seems weird to me because my PHP function should respond with $error.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on what your issue is. Your last point is `... how can I get my PHP response checked first so I can get both $error = "Start point is missing."; and $error = "End point is missing."; responses from my PHP function.`

Comment: Sorry for making it not so clear. What I meant to say is that getStartCoordinates() function inside #addNewModal.click function is executed even when both start and end inputs inside a modal are empty. This causes error of geometry being undefined because it cannot find coordinates based on the empty input. Therefore, I am trying to find a solution to ensure that both $_POST['start] and $_POST['end'] variables will be checked first in the PHP script before executing this getStartCoordinates() function.

Comment: Oh, I just mentioned that in my update. This is going to be client side validation on the start and end text inputs. I suggest changing the `$("#addNewModal").click` to check `if ($("#start").val() && $("#end").val())`, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check your values before attempting to use the google geocoder (that is where your `geometry is not defined` error is coming from). Doing some simple client side validation on the click event can prevent this error and provide some helpful hints on how to proceed. Something like this:

```
$("#addNewModal").click(function() {
    if (validateInputs()) {
        getStartCoordinates();
    } else {
        alert('Please verify start location, end location, and date fields are set');
    }
});

function validateInputs() {
    return $("#start").val() && $("#end").val() && $("#date").val();
}

function getStartCoordinates() {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': $("#start").val()
        },
        function(result, status) {
            if (status = google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                startLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
                startLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
                // getStartCoordinates(); // This likely shouldn't be here.
            }
            getEndCoordinates();
        }
    );
}

function getEndCoordinates() {
    geocoder.geocode({
            'address': $("#end").val()
        },
        function(result, status) {
            if (status = google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                endLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
                endLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
            }

            addRequest();
        }
    );
}
```

Once you are able to submit the correct data from your form to the server side / PHP function you ought to return all errors from the server at once. This should just be appending the errors together and prompting the user. Changing the php function should work like so:

```
$error = "";

if (!$_POST['start']) {
    $error .= "Start point is missing. ";
}

if (!$_POST['end']) {
    $error .= "End point is missing. ";
}

if (!$_POST['date']) {
    $error .= "Date is missing. ";
}

if ($error != "") {    
    echo $error;
    exit();   
} else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO offer (start, end, date, startLng, startLat, endLng, endLat) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['start'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['end'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['date'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['startLng'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['startLat'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['endLng'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['endLat'])."')";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);

    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you.